# Exporting Tables from Access to Excel with conditional formatting done in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

How to do conditional formatting in Access VBA for Excel?

The code would have to be in the database as eventually people will be able to select their own file locations. But that is an issue for another time.

I was thinking of using a function to see under the main section of code (ends at `End Sub`). What would work better: a function or trying to do it in the loop?

```vb
Public Sub ModifyExportedExcelFileFormats(sFile As String)
On Error GoTo Err_ModifyExportedExcelFileFormats

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim x1Rng As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlSheet = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile).Sheets("Full_List")

With xlApp
    .Application.Sheets("Full_List").Select
    .Application.Cells.Select
    .Application.Selection.ClearFormats
    .Application.Rows("1:1").Select
    .Application.Selection.Font.Bold = True
    .Application.Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 41
    .Application.Selection.RowHeight = 38.25
    .Application.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    .Application.Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save
    .Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    .Quit
End With

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing

vStatusBar = SysCmd(acSysCmdClearStatus)

Exit_ModifyExportedExcelFileFormats:
    Exit Sub

Err_ModifyExportedExcelFileFormats:
    vStatusBar = SysCmd(acSysCmdClearStatus)
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_ModifyExportedExcelFileFormats

End Sub


Public Function GetCelColor(ByRef CelVal As Long) As Long
Select Case True

Case CelVal = 1: GetCelColor = RGB(222, 0, 0): Exit Function
Case CelVal < 1: GetCelColor = RGB(0, 111, 0): Exit Function
Case CelVal > 1: GetCelColor = RGB(0, 0, 255): Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: The icon set we're planning to use are traffic lights so red, yellow and green. Red when < 2, Yellow when < 4 and >=2 and Green if its >=4

Table size currently is 2540 rows. The traffic lights be used from A2:M2540. 

ideally it would stop once its reached the end of whatever number of cells there are so if its only 100 cells then its A2:M100 or if its 5000 cells A2:M5000

If you need anymore information I am happy to provide

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with current code. Undesired results? Errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Excel conditional formatting traffic light icon set then no need to set the colours.

This code uses late binding so no need to set a reference to Excel.

**Edit:** After reading your comment I've added a `LastCell` function so it will find the last cell containing data on the worksheet and add the conditional formatting to columns A:M down to that row.

You'll need to supply the correct path name and un-comment the sheet selection code.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Main "S:\Book3.xlsx"

End Sub

Public Sub Main(sFile)

    Dim oXL As Object
    Dim oWrkBk As Object
    Dim owrkSht As Object

    Set oXL = CreateXL
    Set oWrkBk = oXL.workbooks.Open(sFile)
    'Set oWrkSht = oWrkBk.worksheets("Full_List")

    'Testing
    'Set oWrkBk = oXL.workbooks.Add
    Set owrkSht = oWrkBk.worksheets(1)

    With owrkSht
        .cells.clearformats
        With .rows("1:1")
            With .Font
                .Bold = True
                .colorindex = 2
            End With
            .Interior.colorindex = 41
            .RowHeight = 38.25
            .verticalalignment = -4108 'xlCenter
        End With

        With .Range(.cells(2, 2), .cells(LastCell(owrkSht).row, 13))

            'Clear any conditional formatting first.
            'This won't need doing if the workbook is new.
            .FormatConditions.Delete

            .FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
            .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
            With .FormatConditions(1)
                .ReverseOrder = False
                .ShowIconOnly = False
                .IconSet = oWrkBk.IconSets(4) 'xl3TrafficLights1
                With .IconCriteria(2)
                    .Type = 0 'xlConditionValueNumber
                    .Value = 2
                    .Operator = 7
                End With
                With .IconCriteria(3)
                    .Type = 0 'xlConditionValueNumber
                    .Value = 4
                    .Operator = 7
                End With
            End With

        End With
    End With

    With oWrkBk
        .Save
        .Close
    End With

End Sub

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Object, Optional Col As Long = 0) As Object

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        If Col = 0 Then
            lLastCol = .cells.Find("*", , , , 2, 2).Column
            lLastRow = .cells.Find("*", , , , 1, 2).row
        Else
            lLastCol = .cells.Find("*", , , , 2, 2).Column
            lLastRow = .Columns(Col).Find("*", , , , 2, 2).row
        End If

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Public Function CreateXL(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpXL As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    oTmpXL.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateXL = oTmpXL

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateXL."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Also note - no mention of the word `Select` or `Selection` within the code.  It's rare that you have to select a range before making changes to it - it often means you don't have to disable screen updating as well as your screen stops flickering when the ranges were selected.

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot. I'll try it and see what happens i'll get back to you